# Handling large data set(100000) on Google Map using angular2

Tags: performance, angular, google-maps

I am using google map in my angular2 app. I have also used MarkerCluster as below.

```
 for (let marker of this._markers) {

        let lat = +marker.latitude;
        let long = +marker.longitude;

        let markerobj = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long),
            title: marker.name,
            icon: {
                path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
                scale: 6,
                fillOpacity: 0.8,
                fillColor: '#5A7793',
                strokeColor: '#FFFFFF',
                strokeWeight: 2,
            },
            map: this.map,
            visible: true,
        });
        this.markerLayer.push(markerobj);
        latlngbounds.extend(markerOnMap.getPosition());
        markerList.push(markerOnMap);
    }

 let markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(this.map, markerList, { imagePath: '../assets/images' });
```

I want to show around 100000 markers on google map. I am facing lot of performance issues when i tried to plot 100000 markers.

As per client requirement I can not use other map libraries. I need to stick with Google Map.

Do you have any suggestion which help me to improve the performance.

Comment: How is this related to Angular? Does it perform better if you use it without Angular? What value does a view with 100k markers provide? You could just show a red square, the customer probably won't recognize the difference ;-)

Comment: Yes, It does not related to Angular.

Comment: If it is only slow in Angular, you'd need to show the Angular code that makes it slow.

Comment: I have to show count at least. I have seen few examples which uses client+server side clustering. So i want to know if same is possible with google maps.

Answer (score 0):

You don't plot 100,000 markers at once. What you need to do is reduce the amount of data you are displaying at a time. Only display individual markers when you are zoomed in so there are not so many markers in the view.

So what I would suggest is that load the markers from the server based on the bounds of your google map. So that would be the coordinates at the top left and bottom right.

So lets say you have 100,000 markers spread all over the world. At the world view it would be best not to show anything and ask the user to zoom in. Once you are at a lower zoom level use the bounds of the map to get markers from the server which lie inside those bounds. This should reduce the number of markers you have to display substantially. I don't know the coverage of your data but you can figure out what zoom levels work best for you.